# Prove that if $\lim _{x\to \infty } f(x)$ exists ,then $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Let $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be a continuous function such that $\int _0^\infty f(x)\text{dx}$ exists.

> Prove that
>
> - If $\lim _{x\to \infty }  f(x)$ exists, then $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=0$
> - If $f$ is non-negative then $\lim _{x\to \infty }  f(x)$ must exist and  $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=0$

**My try**

To prove that $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=0$ we should show that $\exists G>0$ such that $x>G\implies |f(x)|<\epsilon $ for any $\epsilon>0$

But I can't find out how to show this.
Please help.

Comment: The second proposition is false, for the first one suppose that the limit of $f$ is not zero and show that the integral of $f$ is not bounded in that case.

Comment: @Renart Can you provide a counter-example for the second one?

Comment: i'll post an answer

Comment: See this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/406873/f-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-is-continuous-and-int-0-infty-fxdx-exists?rq=1

Comment: That's the kind of thing i had in mind

Comment: @learnmore Where did you get this?

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty standard. Let $F(x) = \int_{0}^{x}f(t)\,dt$ then we are given that $\lim_{x \to \infty}F(x) = L$ exists. Now by continuity of $f$ and fundamental theorem of calculus we have $F'(x) = f(x)$ and we are given that $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty}F'(x) = M$ also exists. We can see via mean value theorem that $$F(x + 1) - F(x) = F'(\xi) = f(\xi)$$ where $x < \xi < x + 1$. Letting $x \to \infty$ in the above equation and noting that $\xi \to \infty$ we get $$L - L = M$$ or $M = 0$ so that $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.

Second statement is false and counterexample is in the following figure (taken from the masterpiece *A Course of Pure Mathematics* by G. H. Hardy):

[image]

Answer (score -2):

For all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ larger than 1,

Let 
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0 \ for \ x\leq n
\\
n^4x-n^5 \ for \ n<x\leq n+1/n^3
\\
-n^4+2n+n^5 \ for \ n+1/n^3<x\leq n+2/n^3
\end{cases}$$
By some calculation
$\int_n^{n+1}f(x)dx=1/n^2$. Then $\int_0^\infty f(x) = \sum_{n=2}^\infty 1/n^2$.

But $lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: Your function is not defined on $[0, \infty)$

Comment: I defined values of f  for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ larger than 1, so f is defined on [0,$\infty$].

Comment: You actually define a sequence of functions, it's not the same thing