# T/F: if $\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ converges then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = 0$.

Tags: calculus

I was asked to prove or disprove the following:

If $\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ converges then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = 0$.

I said that this is false and gave this example:

$f(x) = \left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  1  & \mbox{if } x \in \mathbb{Q} \\
  -1 & \mbox{if } x \notin \mathbb{Q}
 \end{array}
\right.$

$\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)dx = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ does not exist.

Was my example correct? And could anyone please elaborate more on this topic and write a little about how I should think in case I encounter similar T/F questions in the future?

Comment: Dirichlet function is not Riemann integrable

Comment: Can you explain more? I was not told $f$ is continuous

Comment: $f$ does not have to be continuous. But it must be integrable, obviously, otherwise the question makes no sense.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 I edited my post... Can you please explain why the function I provided is not Reimann integrable?

Comment: Continuous example(s): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral

Comment: For the OP function, the integral does not converge.

Comment: Why? Isn't $\delta x = \frac{b-a}{n} = 0$ always?

Comment: A function is Riemann integrable if and only if its set of discontinuous points has measure $0$.  Your function is discontinuous at every point.  In case you have not learned about measure, the real line does not have measure $0$.

Comment: See the counterexample mentioned in this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1823476/72031 Here the counter examples takes non-negative values only. Thus infinite integrals (integrals on unbounded intervals) are somewhat similar to infinite series but there are some differences (the $n$-th term of convergent series goes to zero, but a similar counterpart does not exist in the theory of convergent integrals).

Answer (score 2):

This is an old friend. If $f$ may be discontinuous, as a counterexample you can propose
$$
f(x) = \chi_{\{n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}}(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1 &\text{if $x \in \mathbb{N}$}\\
0 &\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
If you want a continuous counterxample, you must play with "bump" functions, for instance a function that is mostly zero but that has small bumps of smaller and smaller area.

Comment: Thanks! What is this function you wrote? I'm not familiar with it. And, can you provide a continuous counterexample please?

Comment: @JaneR You should try to construct a counterexample by yourself. Start from the discontinuous example above, and draw small triangle with one side on the $x$-axis. Now you should make these triangles smaller and smaller, so that the infinite sum of their areas is convergent. See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85975/integrable-function-f-on-mathbb-r-does-not-imply-that-limit-fx-is-zero

Answer (score 0):

The statement is false in general. See Fresnel-Integrals
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos(t^2)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(t^2)=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{4} $$